# How to remove unknown ads from appearing on a Laravel php website?

Tags: php, laravel, mobile, mobile-website

[image]

There is an unknown ad appearing on my client's website when visiting the website from a mobile device. I have attached the image with this post here. The website's Web Framework is Laravel & Programming Language used is PHP.

Is there a way to remove the ad from the website? Would appreciate the kind help.

Comment: There is no way to know from where the ad came from, is from the code? browser? extension?

Comment: @SpaceDogCS Thanks for your response. Can you please tell me what could be done to remove this ad?

Comment: It depends from where it cames, if you have the source code or the address to the website I could help

Comment: This ad was injected in code, you just have to access the code and remove the element 
 with the classes adsbygoogle and adsbygoogle-noablate

Comment: Or maybe, on Google Adsense account, it is configured to show dynamically ads on this website

Comment: It has tags as `google-site-verification` and scripts `<script src="https://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/cookie.js?domain=itecounsel.com&amp;callback=_gfp_s_&amp;client=ca-pub-6706699637920296&amp;cookie=ID%3D53a22dc73251427d-22375751bfb900e6%3AT%3D1619016388%3ART%3D1619016388%3AS%3DALNI_MbQ6t0RMRRTn2vOHeYnpbo59mWB1g"></script>`

Comment: @SpaceDogCS thank you very much for the quick fix. I have a web developer who has access to the backend of this website. Can you tell me what I should instruct him to do in order to remove the ad from the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231425/discussion-between-iftekhar-and-spacedogcs).

Answer (score 2):

This ad was automatically added by Google, probably configured by another developer on Google Adsense, There's two ways of removing it, the first one is on Google Adsense panel, just login and disable the ad.

The other one, is removing the script `<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` from the head, the `src` attribute might have some extra code on the ending, but the beggining is the same